# Sum multiple metrics without summing over a wildcard?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have the following metrics:

- `folsomite.<host>.cache.hit1`
- `folsomite.<host>.cache.hit2`
- `folsomite.<host>.cache.miss1`
- `folsomite.<host>.cache.miss2`
- `folsomite.<host>.cache.miss3`

*(The caching library I'm using has 2 flavours of hit: first-chance and second-chance, and 3 flavours of miss)*

And I want to calculate `(hit1 + hit2) / (miss1 + miss2 + miss3)`. I thought I'd start by calculating `(hit1 + hit2)`, but if I use `sumSeries` as `sumSeries(folsomite.*.cache.hit*)`, then it sums over the `<host>` values as well.

How do I sum multiple metrics over some wildcards, without summing over other wildcards? Or how do I specifically add two (or more metrics), while preserving the wildcards?

And, having done that, can I divide one (summed) result by another?

**Edit:** I'm actually using grafana to render the graphs. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 13):

Note I have not solve this, but info could be helpful. Let's assume there are below data in graphite

```
folsomite.A.cache.hit1
folsomite.B.cache.hit1
folsomite.A.cache.hit2
folsomite.C.cache.hit1
folsomite.B.cache.hit2
folsomite.A.cache.miss1
folsomite.B.cache.miss1
folsomite.A.cache.miss2
folsomite.A.cache.miss3
folsomite.C.cache.miss2
folsomite.B.cache.miss2
```

To group by one wildcard, you should use [**groupByNode**](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode) so

```
groupByNode(folsomite.*.cache.hit*, 1, 'sumSeries')
```

will output metrics `A`, `B`, `C` with summed hits. Since groupByNode on miss will returns the same names of metric, we should distinguish it somehow. Use **aliasSub**. So now we have:

```
aliasSub(groupByNode(folsomite.*.cache.hit*, 1, 'sumSeries'), '(.*)', '\1.hit')
aliasSub(groupByNode(folsomite.*.cache.miss*, 1, 'sumSeries'), '(.*)', '\1.miss')
```

and metric we get are `A.hit`, `B.hit`, `C.hit`, `A.miss`, `B.miss`, `C.miss`.

Next we could try [**reduceSeries**](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.reduceSeries) (this is not working for me, I am missing something :) ). Since reduce expect list of series to work on, it need to be combine by [**group**](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.group) or [**mapSeries**](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode), so

```
group(
  aliasSub(groupByNode(folsomite.*.cache.hit*, 1, 'sumSeries'), '(.*)', '\1.hit'), 
  aliasSub(groupByNode(folsomite.*.cache.miss*, 1, 'sumSeries'), '(.*)', '\1.miss')
)
```

will output altogether miss and hit series. Now reduce

```
 reduceSeries(
   group(
     aliasSub(groupByNode(folsomite.*.cache.hit*, 1, 'sumSeries'), '(.*)', '\1.hit'),
     aliasSub(groupByNode(folsomite.*.cache.miss*, 1, 'sumSeries'), '(.*)', '\1.miss')
   ), 'divideSeries', 1, 'hit', miss')
```

That's all. Maybe later I will try different approach but... I hope it will give at least some hint.

And since grafana have ability to set templates with variables it is possible with it, but I would have to dig into this feature.